NTFS Permissions - Folder Traversal
I want to have users be able to look through file shares/directories to reach sub folders they have access to. One example is:
   [Root Folder]
   [Sub Folder 1] ,[Sub Folder 2], [Sub         Folder 3] 
   [Sub Folder A] 

Currently, the user can click into the Root folder, but see nothing. They have permissions for Sub Folder A (which is inside of sub folder1) and can access it when pasting in the file path. I want my user to be able to click into the root folder, see the sub folder 1, so they can then click into Sub folder A (without seeing anything else). My share permissions are set to full perms, and my security permissions restrict what the user can see.
Does any of this make sense? Is it even possible for this share/security mix to work this way? When I give users full access to the root folder or even sub folder, they can see everything properly, but since this user only needs access to sub folder A, it looks like they don't have access period (until they type in the directory).

In Windows terminology, what you're looking for is not traversal but a form of read permission.
Traversal is the ability to access SubFolderA by its exact path (which your users can already do); technically it would be granted by "Traverse Folder / Execute File", but current Windows versions automatically grant it to everyone regardless of ACLs.
But in order to actually see the contents of RootFolder (even partial contents), you need a read or enumerate permission – i.e. you're looking for access-based enumeration.
As far as I could find, Windows only supports access-based enumeration on SMB shares (and specifically only DFS-enabled SMB shares, although that doesn't require any infrastructure, just an additional switch to flip) – could not find any resources about enabling it on local NTFS storage:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-namespaces/enable-access-based-enumeration-on-a-namespace
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/access-based-enumeration-abe-concepts-part-1-of-2/ba-p/400435
https://woshub.com/enable-access-based-enumeration-in-windows-server/

Instead of ABE, one simpler alternative is to grant everyone non-inheritable "Read/List" permission on RootFolder, so that they could see all direct descendants (files and subfolders) without actually being able to open them.
A third method would be to either provide pre-made shortcuts (.lnk) or create symbolic links (mklink) that lead directly into the deeper folder, without users having to know the path.

Thank you for this information. I like the idea of your last comment, but my executive team is fickle and they don't want users to see anything, even the file name....
I will have to check on my settings to see if Acess -Based Enumeration is on/off. Will update when I have the chance to.

You could solve that by having strictly no files in the toplevel directory – segment it e.g. by team or project first. But if that doesn't work, then I'd keep the security structure you have and provide users with symlinks or shortcuts into the deeper folders. As far as I know, it is not a particularly good idea to rely on ABE as a security mechanism; it's more of a convenience feature.
